# Package-scope non-null annotation in Java for Kotlin (built by Gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety, jsr305

I'm trying to write a Java library that has a non-nullable API, and I'd like Kotlin to properly infer this non-nullability. I'm using [JSR-305](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jar) annotations and its `@TypeQualifierDefault` to achieve the effect for the entire package, as per [Kotlin's Java interop reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#type-qualifier-defaults-since-1150).

I build it all using Gradle 4.10.2 and I supply `-Xjsr305=strict` to the Kotlin compiler, [as instructed](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#compiler-configuration). Yet, when I reflectively inspect the types from Kotlin, they are reported as [platform types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types), e.g.:

```
fun sample.Foo.bar(T!): kotlin.collections.(Mutable)List<T!>!
```

What am I doing wrong that I don't get the following output?

```
fun sample.Foo.bar(T): kotlin.collections.(Mutable)List<T>
```

Note that Spring Framework 5 has a similar annotation named [`@NonNullApi`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/NonNullApi.html).

I'm using OpenJDK 11.

PS. I know I can just annotate every method and parameter with `@Nonnull`, but I'm after global behavior and converting Kotlin's `List<T!>` to `List<T>`.

---

Here's the MCVE:

- src/main/java/sampleAnnotation/NonNullPackage.java

  ```
  package sampleAnnotation;

  import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
  import javax.annotation.meta.TypeQualifierDefault;
  import java.lang.annotation.*;

  @Nonnull
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target(ElementType.PACKAGE)
  @TypeQualifierDefault({
          ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE
  })
  public @interface NonNullPackage {
  }
  ```
- src/main/java/foo/package-info.java

  ```
  @NonNullPackage
  package foo;

  import sampleAnnotation.NonNullPackage;
  ```
- src/main/java/foo/Foo.java

  ```
  package foo;

  import java.util.List;

  public interface Foo {
      <T> List<T> bar(T t);
  }
  ```
- src/main/kotlin/sampleKotlin/Main.kt

  ```
  package sampleKotlin

  import foo.Foo
  import kotlin.reflect.full.memberFunctions

  fun main(args : Array<String>) {
      println(Foo::class.memberFunctions.first())
  }
  ```
- build.gradle

  ```
  plugins {
      id 'java'
      id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.0'
  }

  wrapper {
      gradleVersion = '4.10.2'
  }

  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
      compileOnly group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '3.0.2'

      compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib'
      compile group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect'
  }

  compileKotlin {
      kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
  }
  ```

Comment: What happens when you actually use your Java class and, for example, try to pass null as argument or check a retrn value for null? Does it behave as expected, or not?

Comment: @JBNizet Sorry for late reply. Indeed, when I try to compile method like `fun baz(foo: Foo) { foo.bar(null) }` I get "Null can not be a value of a non-null type Nothing". Thanks! As far as I understand, it means there's some bug in Kotlin reflection, right? And I have to think of another way of checking programatically if my API is seen as expected in Kotlin.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug. To me, it just shows that they're still platform types, but that the compiler use their annotations to help you use them.

Comment: @JBNizet Well, it feels like a bug to me :) For example, if I define `class FooImpl implements Foo { public <T> List<T> bar(T t) { return null; } }` (for which I get a warning in IntelliJ), and then I write `val list = FooImpl().bar("")` in Kotlin, it compiles without errors but at runtime, it throws "FooImpl().bar("") must not be null". In other words, the return type is *not* considered by Kotlin to be a platform type neither at compile time nor at runtime. I'll report it to JetBrains to see how they view it :)

Comment: Reported as [KT-28009](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28009).